# Iron Prince Rupert's drop

Tags: materials, thermodynamics, structures

I'm wondering if molten iron was hurled into outer space if it might create a shape similar to a Prince Rupert's drop. Like, say, if a star had finally exhausted it's fuel and exploded.

Comment: Would this have a better fit in Astronomy?

Comment: If only hurling things into space could solve ALL of life's problems.

Comment: @SolarMike, apparently it's for a story.  This should be migrated to WorldBuilding.

Comment: @Wossname any candidates - political?

Comment: I would agree with WorldBuilding

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely.

Space is a vacuum.  Vacuums are very poor thermal conductors (consider Thermos flasks), so the iron ball would cool rather slowly which is precisely the opposite of what you need.

Dropping it into something like a very large vat of liquid nitrogen (with forced circulation), might yield something structurally similar to the glass drops.

However metal is a great deal more flexible than glass when solid, so anything that would normally cause a glass PRD to shatter spectacularly would probably only cause the metal version to snap in half in a rather disappointing manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why this probably wouldn't work.

Firstly in order to be hardenable iron needs a fairly specific set of additional alloying elements ie it needs to be steel. For maximum hardness and hardenability you are looking at around 0.7 - 1.2 % carbon much less and it won't get very hard at all, much more and you are getting more towards cast iron.

Also plain carbon steel needs pretty rapid cooling to harden, generally in the order of a few second from critical temperature (around 800c)  to below the transition temperature (around 200C)  and this generally requires a quenching medium, typically oil or water depending on the mass and section thickness involved. There are steels which will harden in a stream of air but these tend to have a fairly high chromium content eg [A2 tool steel](http://www.steelexpress.co.uk/toolsteel/A2-Steel-properties.html).

The problem here is that while space is cold heat transfer tends to be slow because radiation is the only mechanism available and I suspect that it won;t cool fast enough to harden.

Whether you could get a workable alloy from stellar reactions I don't really know. Meteoric iron can certainly contain nickel but I've never heard of naturally occurring steel as such.